# How to use Selenium tests?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, automation

I start to learn how to automate my tests.
I learn this: http://anoopjshetty.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/creating-test-automation-framework-using-c-selenium-and-nunit/

But this in this case result is dll file with selenium tests.
For run test in that manual uses NUnit app.

But what (or how) I must do if I need to control those tests from my application?
I mean I need to click button on my application and it will run tests from that class?

Comment: What application? WinForms? ASP.NET WebForms? MVC? Console application? Classic ASP?

Comment: are you trying to not use a dll file? if so, good luck with that one.  how do you expect to use selenium without the dll?

Comment: @sircapsalot, no, I wanna to use test cases in my own application, with or without dll it isn't matter. But Without NUnit application.

Comment: @Arran, WinForms, sorry that I haven't noticed it earlier

Comment: If you are using Selenium, you don't _have_ to use `NUnit` to run your tests; Selenium has built-in mechanisms that can run the tests for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is asnwer that I was expected, step by step:

1. create dll with selenium tests code;
2. create new WinForms project;
3. Add references -> Browse -> select our DLL;
4. also add line using OURDLLNAME;
5. finally use our test methods in our winforms application.

In this case there is no need to use NUnit