# Is there any api provided in VS 2012 to create Unit test cases for WinForm applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Windows Form application. Now I need to write Unit Test Cases for this. The 'visualstudio.testtools.unittesting' framework provide Unit Test support. But I do not believe it provide APIs for writing test cases for a WinForm class.

I have researched and found about NunitForms but it seems limited in terms of supported controls. Also if someone find good documentations/tutorials on this please share.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the MS Built-in Unit Testing framework(MSTEST), is preferably good for standard Unit Tests IMO. However you can try [MSTest Coded UI testing target winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390916/can-i-run-coded-ui-tests-from-windows-froms-applications) UI elements. If that's does not support the next best option is using a [3rd party framework](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Coded-UI/).

I have personally worked on a winforms project and used [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003213/how-to-use-selenium-tests).

Comment: Thank you for your response Spock. I am looking for APIs which let me write Unit Tests for Winform event handler like btnSubmit_Click.  
The CodedUI and Selenium are for Automation test.

Comment: Then why not use MVPVM pattern which allows you to abstract away the Click handler and write test against a Presenter for what happens inside the click handler?